# Which child process send SIGCHLD

Tags: c, signals, sigchld

I'm trying to understand the signal handling and process. I have a parent process that created several child processes. Now in the parent process I have a list of all child processes. when a child is terminated I want to delete it from the list. I know that when a child is terminated he's sending `SIGCHLD` to the parent. OK, now it's the tricky part, how can I find out if that child terminated or just suspended or something else?

Comment: WIFSIGNALED and WIFSTOPPED, macros applied to the status returned by `wait`

Comment: @ William Pursell, but if the process suspended it will be stuck at `wait` until it terminated

Answer (score 3):

As you said

> when a child is terminated he's sending SIGCHLD to the parent

Make the parent call [`wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Either

- by a blocking call to `wait()` or
- on a continous base or
- by seting up a signal handler serving `SIGCHLD` which in turn calls `wait()`.

If having called `waitpid()` with a pid of `-1` using the option `WUNTRACED` and then applying the macro `WIFSTOPPED` to the value returend by `waitpid()` it tells you whether the process was stopped or ended.

For Linux since kernel version 2.6.10 the same as for `WIFSTOPPED` applies to `WCONTINUED`.

Comment: I looked at the man page for `wait` and `waitpid` and I saw that `wait` don't have `option` field (which `waitpid` have)

Answer (score 1):

There is a system call in *signal.h* - **sigaction()** , similar to *siganl( )* but more useful.
Visit http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

The signal handler function prototype for *sigaction()* looks like this:

```
void sa_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext);
```

It has an argument of type siginfo_t which contains all the information about the signal including the pid of the process which sent it.
Though using conventional signal handling mechanism, it can be done using *waitid()* as mentioned in previous answer(s) but *waitid()* needs *pid* as one of its argument.

Answer (score 0):

Using the options argument of the wait() family of functions (waitpid(),waitid()).

[http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitid](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait)